# Tkinter Button Doesn't Perform Action

Tags: python, tkinter

Full disclosure, I am a Python newb, and even newer to Tkinter.  I have the below code which I was able to parse together from various sources which shows the buttons and dialogue box as I want them to be shown.  The "Cancel" button works appropriately, but when I enter proper credentials and click "OK", nothing happens.  Based on what I have read, I think I may have a binding and/or callback issue, but I am not sure.  After several hours of reading and watching YouTube videos, I am banging my head against the desk.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
from Tkinter import *
    master = Tk()

    def login_info():
        bankUsername = bank_user.get()
        bankPassword = bank_pass.get()
        return

    Label(master, text=str(properBankName) + " Username: ").grid(row=0, sticky = "E")
    Label(master, text="Password: ").grid(row=1, sticky = "E")

    master.title("Please Enter Credentials")

    bank_user = Entry(master)
    bank_pass = Entry(master)

    bank_user.grid(row=0, column=1)
    bank_pass.grid(row=1, column=1)

    Button(master, height=1, width=8, text='OK', command=login_info).grid(row=3, column=0, sticky = "E", pady=4)
    Button(master, height=1, width=8, text='Cancel', command=master.quit).grid(row=3, column=1, sticky = "W", pady=4)

    master.mainloop()
```

Comment: All the OK button does is set two variables. How do you know it's not working?

Comment: function `login_info` gets two values and later do NOTHING because you did't add any other code. So don't expect magic. BTW: put in `login_info` function `print("I'm in login_info")` and you will se text (in console) when you click button.

Comment: Your login_info sets two local variables and then throws them away.

Comment: It does indeed set the variables, which I have confirmed by using the `Print` function.  My expectation is that once I clicked "Ok", the dialogue box would close and the remainder of the script would execute.

Comment: `return` ends only `login_info` function - nothing more. You could close window using `master.quit()` or `master.destroy()` and then it will executes code which you will have after `mainloop()` - but you don't have any code after `mainloop()`. And `bankUsername`, `bankPassword` are local variables which will not exist when you leave function `login_info`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use global variables to keep values and then I use `master.destroy()` to close window.
(on Linux `master.quit()` doesn't execute `master.destroy()` which close window)

I use variable `login` to recognize which button was clicked.

I use `columnspan=2` for `Entry` and move `Buttons` one cell to the right - and now it looks better.

BTW: lines `Button(...).grid(...)` were very long so I splited them into two lines to make more readable.

Code:

```
from Tkinter import *

# --- functions ---

def login_info():
    # inform function to use external/global variables
    global bankUsername
    global bankPassword
    global login

    login = True

    bankUsername = bank_user.get()
    bankPassword = bank_pass.get()

    # quit window 
    master.destroy()

# --- main ---

# create global variables
bankUsername = None
bankPassword = None
login = False

# - GUI

master = Tk()

Label(master, text="Username:").grid(row=0, sticky="E")
Label(master, text="Password:").grid(row=1, sticky="E")

master.title("Please Enter Credentials")

bank_user = Entry(master)
bank_pass = Entry(master)

bank_user.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=2)
bank_pass.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=2)

b = Button(master, height=1, width=8, text='OK', command=login_info)
b.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky="E", pady=4)

b = Button(master, height=1, width=8, text='Cancel', command=master.destroy)
b.grid(row=3, column=2, sticky="W", pady=4)

master.mainloop()

# --- executed after closing window ---

if login: # if login is True:
    print(bankUsername)
    print(bankPassword)
else:
    print("Canceled")
```